# Adding an Easy Share Action in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, share-button

I have problem. I was follow a lot of guides, but still can't get my Share button to work. I got the icon showing in ActionBar, but when I press nothing is happening when android:showAsAction="always". But when android:showAsAction="never" it works. I just want share icon to be always shown in ActionBar. What I am doing wrong? Please help

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.shareButton);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.shareButton:
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "Check it out";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            return true;
        case R.id.aboutButton:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:title="@string/share"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>  **---> when I put here "NEVER" then it works! But I want Share to be always as icon**

    <item
        android:id="@+id/aboutButton"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/about_dev"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you didn´t find a solution try this to get the ShareActionProvider

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share)
            .getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(doShare());
    return true;
}
```

And `doShare()` would be:

```
    public Intent doShare() {
    // populate the share intent with data
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Put whatever you want");
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Following this approach I would have to know the data to share when the options menu is created. But what when I only know which data to share when the button is actually clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Try "Intent share = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND)" instead.
You seem to be doing everything right!

Answer (score 0):

In

```
case R.id.shareButton:
```

instead of using

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

use:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
```

Refer the following links for more information:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html#set-share-intent